# How to allow multiple users access to same page

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have 2 sets of users that need access to a shared page. Each user has a different session assigned. Here is what I have. It allows access to 'client1' but not 'admin'

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["client1"]) || $_SESSION["client1"] !== true) {
header("Location: ../../../login.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION["admin"]) || $_SESSION["admin"] !== true) {
header("Location: ../../../login.php");
exit;
   }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION["client1"]) && $_SESSION["client1"] == true) || (isset($_SESSION["admin"]) && $_SESSION["admin"] == true) {
//show page

}else {
    header("Location: ../../../login.php");
}{
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It needed an extra set of () around the whole thing. I got it working.